# How to prevent error when deleting last DataRow from DataTable bound to DataGridView?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

In my WinForms application, I have the following logic triggered by a button press:

```
    private void ExecuteSelectedConsoleCommand()
    {
        var commandsRow = GetCommandsRow();
        var consoleCommand = GetConsoleCommand(commandsRow);
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            var runningCommandRow =
                  runtimeDataSet.RunningCommands.AddRunningCommandsRow(Guid.NewGuid(),
                  consoleCommand.OneLineDescription);

            consoleCommand.Run(null);

            runningCommandRow.Delete();
        });
    }
```

A BindingSource is used to let a DataGridView automatically update itself.

As of now, without the following hack, I get an error saying the the "index 0 is invalid".

```
        // prevents error when removing last row from data bound datagridview
        var placeholder = runtimeDataSet
                             .RunningCommands
                             .AddRunningCommandsRow(Guid.NewGuid(), "PLACEHOLDER");
```

With the above code, which causes there to always be at least one row in the DataGridView, it works fine.

How do I fix this?

Note: This seems like something many others would have run into, but my web searches have failed..

Comment: Could you describe the problem with a more general code?

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem. After some trial and error I have discovered that you have to handle several events of the datagridview to make this go away, and even that requires some error ignoring. I don't remeber precisely what I have done to circumvent this error but I think the following to snippets may offer some insight (explanations in comments):

Remove row:

```
//When I remove a row that has been added, but not commited return from the function
//run the update function only if the row is commited (databound)
private void dgvTest_RowsRemoved(object sender, DataGridViewRowsRemovedEventArgs e) {
    if (_lastDataRow == null || _lastDataRow.RowState == DataRowState.Added)
        return;
    UpdateRowToDatabase();
}
```

Row validating:

```
//I got the kind of Index not valid or other index errors
//RowValidating is fired when entering the row and when leaving it
//In my case there was no point in validating on row enter
private void dgvTest_RowValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)    {
if (Disposing)
     return;
if (!dgvTest.IsCurrentRowDirty) {
     return;
    }
try {
var v = dgvTest.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem;
} catch {
return;
}
}
```

Data error:

```
//I had to trap some errors and change things accordingly
private void dgvTest_DataError(object sender, DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs e) {
        if (e.Exception.Message.Contains("Index") && e.Exception.Message.Contains("does not have a value")) {
            //when editing a new row, after first one it throws an error
            //cancel everything and reset to allow the user to make the desired changes
            bindingSource.CancelEdit();
            bindingSource.EndEdit();
            bindingSource.AllowNew = false;
            bindingSource.AllowNew = true;
            e.Cancel = true;
            dgvTest.Visible = false;
            dgvTest.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

Row enter:

```
 //Some problemes occured when entering a new row
 //This resets the bindingsource's AllowNew property so the user may input new data
 private void dgvTest_RowEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
            if (!_loaded)
                return;
            if (e.RowIndex == dgvTest.NewRowIndex)
                if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dgvTest.Rows[e.RowIndex == 0 ? e.RowIndex : e.RowIndex - 1].Cells[_idColumn].Value.ToStringSafe())) {
                    bindingSource.CancelEdit();
                    bindingSource.AllowNew = false;
                    bindingSource.AllowNew = true;
                }
        }
```

Hope this helps!